# maximal m-elements of the matrix inversion

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible, and all its elements are between 0 and 1. The existing matrix inversion operation of $A^{-1}$ will take $O(n^3)$ time. Now I just want to find the maximal $m$ elements of $A^{-1}$, is it possible to design an algorithm that is less than $O(n^3)$ time?

Comment: usually there are lots of algorithms for sparse matrices, but more often we would consider the structure of the matrices, not the number of elements. There are also some algorithms that reduces the time to $O(n^{2.36})$ by replacing multiplications with additions.